# KnitR XeTeX Beamer issue

Tags: r, latex, knitr, beamer

I am trying to use a Beamer theme that requires `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` with a KnitR document. Here is a minimal example test.Rnw:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
<<include=FALSE>>=
options(tikzDefaultEngine='xetex')
@ 
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
<<echo=FALSE, dev="tikz">>=
plot(1:100)
@
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I Knit the doucument I get:

```
Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics) : 
TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
or character:

    m

Common reasons for failure include:
  * The string contains a character which is special to LaTeX unless
    escaped properly, such as % or $.
  * The string makes use of LaTeX commands provided by a package and
    the tikzDevice was not told to load the package.
```

This is an issue specifically related to the no-math option with fontspec along with dev="tikz". If I remove either of these, the document compiles fine. Any suggestions on how to get this to work? The entire purpose of using a tikz device is to allow the format of my graphics to match up with my theme that requires I am trying to use a Beamer theme that requires `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/119#issuecomment-139672966.